# \D+? Doesn't work in Regex

Tags: .net, regex

I have model names:

```
DP-7451P
MPG 3434
MP-WH40B
MP-W40B
MP-1820G
```

I need to have a regex that can make two or three groups of the above, group 1 should be before the dash (or space), the other should be the preceding number or char set, and the last group should be the final char (it represents the product color).

In my particular scenario, this is what I'm looking for

```
(DP)(7451)(P)
(PZG)(3434)()
(GF)(WH40)(B)
(MP)(W40)(B)
(VRN)(1820)(G)
```

I tried `(\D{2,3})[-|\s](\D+?\d+)(\D+?)`. But it doesn't do the job. Isn't `\D+?` meant to search for zero or more chars that are not a digit? So how do I do it then?

I'm using [this](http://regexr.com?2v0m9) to test my work.

Comment: \D is a non-digit character, \D+ is one or more non-digits and \d+ is one or more digits.

Comment: Exactly, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you escaped the `\\`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `+`character you specify that there's **at least 1** occurrence of the proceeding character. That's why you don't match case 1,2 and 4. You should be using the `*` character instead, which matches **zero** or more.

A couple of other notes to get it to work. First of all we need to specify some anchors, `^ $`, to match it as a whole string. Then we have a group of 1 or more A-Z letters, `[A-Z]+`. This followed by a hyphen or a space, `[-|\s]`. After this come some optional letters, `[A-Z]*`, followed by a variable amount of numbers `\d*`, and finally some optionally letters `[A-Z]*`.

```
^([A-Z]+)[-|\s]([A-Z]*\d+)([A-Z]*)$
```

This regex matches all your [cases](http://regexr.com?2v1o7) in the testcase you provided in you question. Here you can see my regex in action: http://regexr.com?2v1og.

Comment: And you don't need the `?` after it. I think @Shimmy has confused optional/required with lazy/greedy matching.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work as per your requirements

`^(\D{2,3})[-\s](\D*?\d*?)(\D?)$`.

I didn't change much, just replaced `+` with `*`. Another change is the final group matching the color coding which is just one character so I replaced `\D+?` with `\D?`. If your color codes are multiple characters, then you can use `(\D*)` for the final group as well.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, `\D` is the wrong tool for this job.  In your examples, the first chunk of interest consists of two or three (uppercase ASCII) letters, the second is a mix of letters and digits, and the third is a single letter, optional.  If that's always the case, your regex should be:

```
^([A-Z]{2,3})[-\s]([A-Z0-9]+?)([A-Z]?)$
```

...assuming you're matching each part number in isolation.  If you're plucking them out of a larger body of text, word boundaries are probably in order:

```
\b([A-Z]{2,3})[-\s]([A-Z0-9]+?)([A-Z]?)\b
```

If there can be lowercase letters as well, you can add them to the character classes or make the whole regex case-insensitive, but I don't see any use for `\D` (which, by the way, will match hyphens and whitespace as well as letters).

Also, `\D+?` matches **one** or more non-digit characters, not *zero* or more.  The trailing `?` just makes the `+` non-greedy.

Comment: It doesn't work. The 3rd group is selected along with the 2nd.

Comment: You're right, the `+` in the second group should have been non-greedy.  I've edited the answer accordingly.